# using PLINQ or Parallel with keeping original order

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

I have a large collection of elements. I want to call ToString for each element and build one string. 
My first approach was to slow

```
        string str = "";
        list.ForEach( g => {

            string s = g.ToString();
            if(s != "")
                str = str + g.ToString() + "\n";
        });
```

I tried using the Parallel class and PLINQ as shown below but then the order of the elements in the final string was not like in the original.

Parallel

```
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(list, g => {

            string s = g.ToString();
            if(s != "")
                str = str + g.ToString() + "\n";
        });
```

PLINQ

```
        string str = "";
        list.AsParallel().AsOrdered().ForAll( g => {

            string s = g.ToString();
            if(s != "")
                str = str + g.ToString() + "\n";
        });
```

How can I improve the performance and keep the original order?
Thanks

Comment: `AsOrdered()` only perserves the order with regard to the original ordering. So if the order is different after the ForEach then you need to sort it afterwards.

Comment: I don't know how to keep the order (or even if it is possible), but you should use a StringBuilder instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: changed to use Stringbuilder with no parallel and it solved the problem. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think that trying to use parallelism is not the right solution here, using a better algorithm is.

Currently, your code is [O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/41071)(*n*<sup>2</sup>), because each concatenation creates a completely new string and so it has to copy the whole previous string into the new one.

But you can do this om O(n), if you use the mutable `StringBuilder` instead of the immutable `string`. That way, you can just append at the end of the existing `StringBuilder` and you don't have to copy anything.

And you can also achieve the same performance with less code using a special method just for joining strings together: `string.Join()`.

---

But there might be an even better solution: use a `StreamWriter`. For example, if you wanted to write the resulting string to a file, that would be a better solution, because the whole string doesn't need to be in memory at all.

---

Parallelism isn't something that will magically solve all your performance problems. You need to think about what the threads will be doing, especially if you have some shared data (like `str` in your code). In your case, you *could* try to use parallelism, but it wouldn't be that simple and I'm not sure it would actually improve the performance.

It would work like this: each thread would get a range of indexes in the list and concatenate those. At the end, the main thread would then concatenate the results from all threads together. But there is no built-in method for that, so you would need to write all that code by yourself. (This would work, because string concatenation is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative).)